# Cannot use jQuery with express

Tags: jquery, express

I started to study express recently. I'm trying to use jQuery in a HTML document sent to the client with `res.sendFile()` method of express. The HTML looks good on the browser, but the console returns the next message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

What can I do to use jQuery?

**app.js**

```
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();

app.set ('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set ('view engine', 'jade');
app.use ( express.static(__dirname + '/static') );

app.get ('/hello', function (req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get ('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
    console.log ('IP: ' + req.ip);
});

app.get ('/headers', function(req,res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    var s = '';
    for (var name in req.headers) s += name + ': ' + req.headers[name] + '\n';
         res.send(s)
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Express</h1>


<script>

    $("h1").value('Jesus');

</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either you have included jQuery after your custom script or you have a semicolon or something like that is missing.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery script tag in your web page so that jQuery is loaded and available in that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add at the top of your page

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$("h1").text('Jesus'); 
</script>
</head>
```

OR CHANGE YOUR CODE LIKE

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$("h1").text('Jesus'); 
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but now the message is:                       Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: can you show the code ? what have you tried and how ?

Comment: Sorry, now it's ok, the problem was that the method value() does not exist, I'm using text(). Thanks

Comment: you are accessing $('h1').valu('') if you are trying to change the content of h1 use $('h1').html('your content here i.e <div>content</div>'); you can also use $('h1').text('text here i.e "my text"');